# Use multiple collections (or other types) for same "with..." argument?

Tags: vba

I have a range (let's say A1:A100). I have added 7 collections and each collection contains a set of individual cells.

The offset(0,1) row from the "A" column is predetermined and can be any 3 number constellation of "y" and "n". I have written an argument where y=1 and n=0.

Based on this I have written several IF statement (see below for example)

```
If M(1) = 1 And M(2) = 1 And M(3) = 1 Then

    Count = Count + 1   ' unique
    Robust(Count) = SI_number   'unique

    With Robust(Count)               
        .Offset(1, 0) = SI_name  'unique
        .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .Font.Size = 5
        .Font.Name = "xxx"
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    end with

' Robust and T is of type collection
```

Is there some way to use the same "with.." arguments for multiple ranges/collections?

I will have 7 different IF statements. Each will have a specific collection (own name) with individual cells to be used if the condition is met. To avoid a lot of repetitive lines I would like to do (in code):

```
With collection(1-7)
    .action (same code as above)
    .action
    ..
    ..

End with
```

One idea that I had was to create a separate macro which can be called from inside my main macro so that:

```
With X
    .action
    .action
    ..
    ..
End with.
```

Where X can be 1 to 7. With the use of "with" or any other function, is it possible to store collection1, collection 2,..., collection 7 in the same variable (or equivalent type) so in the end of each If statement there is a
X = Collection()

```
Call format 'macro that formats the cell/text
```

Another question is how to add let's say 20 individual cells to a collection? The code is repetitive with several "collection.add range(xx".. etc.

Comment: Could you share the code of 1 of those repetitive tasks and point out what else will be each time unique (if anything) except the ranges and the collections. An idea would be put all 7 collections into an 8th collection and the 7 matching ranges into a 9th collection and then loop from 1 to 7 and do your stuff.

Comment: Hi I just edited my original question. Sorry for not including that initially

Comment: Another idea, what if I do not format until all the cells (about 55) have been assigned proper values. Then I combine the range for all 7 collections, loop through all of them and then do the formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Sub `format()` that should do what you expect, together with a `test_collection()` Sub to test it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test_collection()
    Dim c1 As Collection
    Dim c2 As Collection
    Dim i As Integer

    Set c1 = New Collection
    Set c2 = New Collection

    c1.Add Sheet1.Range("A1")
    c1.Add Sheet1.Range("A2")
    c1.Add Sheet1.Range("A3")

    c2.Add Sheet1.Range("B1")
    c2.Add Sheet1.Range("B2")
    c2.Add Sheet1.Range("B3")

    '''   adding bunch of cells using a loop
    For i = 4 To 20
        c1.Add Sheet1.Range("A" & i)
    Next i

    format c1
    format c2

End Sub

Sub format(in_coll As Collection)
    '''   input is collection and we have to cycle through each individual cell in the collection
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To in_coll.Count
        With in_coll(i)
            '.Offset(1, 0) = SI_name
            .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .Font.Size = 5
            .Font.Name = "xxx"
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

However, using range object is usually much more suitable when working with cells, so here is the code to do the same using Range object instead of collection.

```
Sub test_range()
    Dim c1 As Range
    Dim c2 As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Set c1 = Sheet1.Range("A1:A20")
    Set c2 = Sheet1.Range("B1:B3")

    format_range c1
    format_range c2

End Sub

Sub format_range(in_rng As Range)
    '''   input is range and we can update the cells in a bulk

    With in_rng
        '.Offset(1, 0) = SI_name
        .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .Font.Size = 5
        .Font.Name = "xxx"
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I really appreciate it, I'll give it a go first thing tomorrow morning! Regarding the range thing..I'm new to VBA so I may be overlooking something quite simple now but I'm having trouble with the range argument (I use to many arguments). Can you really store 20 individual cells (non-continuous) in a data type range? For example, C1, D12, E1, G55 etc..?

Comment: Yes you absolutely can. Nice way to thing about the Range object is "any set of cells". For example, if you select 20 (or 20 thousand, whatever) cells in excel, that's a single Range object. Also, each cell on its own is a range object. Try typing this in the VBE Immediate window: `?sheets(1).Range("C1,D12, E1,G55").Address`.

Comment: Thanks once again! Works like a charm. I forgot the "set" in the beginning. I have been using collection for weeks haha

Comment: You are learning me a lot! I really do appreciate it. Just started programming and although I find it really fun, it's incredibly frustrating when I'm unaware of the tools available. In case you would have time, I have another question (hope this isn't too greedy)... I edited my original question (so see above should you have the time).

Comment: Glad to help. Your last question doesn't belong to SO, as it is not a question, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). I looked at it and see nothing I can help with there. You will get much better answers if you ask a new question with a good minimal working example. Also I would delete it from this question.